# Submit form using a hyperlink and a button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have form and the form submission can be done by either clicking on a hyper link or on a submit button. However I want my server to realize what has been used for form submission.

Current code snippet looks like this:

```
<a href=javascript:{} onclick="formSubmit()";>Next</a>
<input type="button" name="search" value="Get Result" onclick = "formSubmit();">
```

And my formSubmit() looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function formSubmit()
 {
     document.getElementById('form1').submit();
     return false;
 }
```

Any pointers as to how to go about it.
Thanks

Comment: Use an `<input type="hidden" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a value (say an `int` or `boolean`) into the function.  The value passed can be used to determine the source.

Comment: This got me searching and with help of hidden input I could get what I was trying for

Answer (score 2):

Use a hidden parameter in your form.

```
< input type="hidden" value="0" name="flag"/>
```

- When the form is submitted using javascript change flag value to '1' in the script.

  ```
  function formSubmit()
  {
   document.form1.flag.value="1";
   document.getElementById('form1').submit();
   return false;
  }
  ```
- in case submit button is pressed the flag = '0'.
- you can get this parameter on the server to determine how the form is submitted

edit : change your button type to 'submit' or call different scripts for both actions.

Comment: Both the link and the button use this function, so how does it help?

Comment: you may change the type of the button to "submit" (so you dont need to call a script) or call different scripts for both the actions.

Comment: Thanks, input type = "hidden" aided my cause !

Answer (score 0):

you invoke the same function to submit the form,so if you want your server to realize what has been used for form submission,i think you must pass a parameter to your server

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.target to get the source that triggered the event and then set a flag to pass to server. See the example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function myFunction(e)
{ 
alert(e.target);
}
</script>
</head>

<p>
Click on a paragraph. An alert box will alert the element that triggered the event.</p>

<p>
<strong>Note:</strong> The target property returns the element that triggered the event, and not necessarily the eventlistener's element.</p>

This Link Click will return "javascript:{}"
<a href=javascript:{} onclick="myFunction(event)";>Next</a>

<p>
This Button Click will return "[objectHTMLInputElement]"
<input type="button" name="search" value="Get Result" onclick = "myFunction(event);"> 
</p>

</body>
</html>
```